# Show Price Range of Simple Product having Custom Option instead of Base Price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

I am working on `Magento 1.9.2.4` and I have to show some simple products on the home page but their price should be displayed in the format of `Price: minimum_price To maximum_price` instead of base price.

Suppose I have a product in the admin panel with name **Gwyneth Basket**

- Its base price **0**
- And Under the custom option, I create a drop-down Like

[image]

Now in the frontend, I have to show **Gwyneth Basket** product like

[image]

It working as desired on category page using [This Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833001/magento-show-price-ranges-of-custom-option-prices-in-list-phtml-instead-of-base/24192189) But how do I achieve this on custom templates.

Thank You

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Piyush Thank You! I try to load product collection as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509478/how-to-show-price-range-of-custom-option-in-magento and above reference link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(1); //product id 1
        $i = 1;
        $array = array();
        echo "<pre>";
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
            $values = $o->getValues();
            foreach ($values as $v) {
                $array[] = $v->getPrice();
            }
            $i++;
            echo "<br/>";

        }
        sort($array); 
        $max = count($array) - 1 ;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo $minPrice = $array[0];
        echo $maxPrice = $array[$max];

        if(empty($array)){
            $price = $product->getPrice();
        }

        echo "Base Price" . $price;
```

Work Fine for me.

Comment: Thank You :) Its working as desired. One question if how do I show base price if custom option is not available?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: you need to just set one condition for base price if custom price array is empty set base price

Comment: ThankYou @AjayPatel :) Happy Coding....