# How to set custom price range in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, custom-prices

I want to show the price range Like this

```
Up to Rs 10000

From 10000 to 25000

From 25000 to 50000

From 50000 to 100000

From 100000 to 300000

Above 300000
```

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add custom price range filter using block. Create a custom block file and then create one function for that fixed price range and call this "getPrice()" function in this file rwd\default\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml and it's working for me.

Block File :

class VendorName_ModuleName_Block_Sidebar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {

public function getPrice(){

```
$currentUrl = Mage::registry('current_category')->getUrl();
//$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc')
                    ->setPageSize(1)
                    ->load();
$maxPrice = round($productCollection->getFirstItem()->getPrice(),2);
$minPrice = round($productCollection->getFirstItem()->getMinimalPrice(),2);

$priceFilterHtml = '';
if($maxPrice <= 500){
    $priceFilterHtml .= "<ul>
        <li><a href= ".$currentUrl."?price=1%2C500>0.00 - ".$maxPrice."</a></li>     
        </ul>";
}else{
    $priceFilterHtml .= "<ul>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=1%2C10000>0.00 - 10,000</a></li>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=1.6666667%2C15000>10,000 - 25,000</a></li>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=2%2C25000>25,000 - 50,000</a></li>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=2%2C50000>50,000- 100,000</a></li>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=1.5%2C200000>100,000- 300,000</a></li>
        <li><a href=".$currentUrl."?price=1.05%2C6000000>300,000 above</a></li>
      </ul>";
}  
  return $priceFilterHtml;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this to show price range for custom options for simple products

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152535/72475

Comment: I want to add custom price range in filter.